# Is there an easy way for a handicapped android to get to the mall?

Tags: nier-automata

Near the beginning of Routes C/D,

> you crash land in the Flooded City as 2B, who then realizes she has been infected with a logic virus.

In an attempt to isolate herself, she decides to make her way to the abandoned commercial facility, which is quite a ways away.

Unfortunately, due to the increasingly bad system failures she experiences, her movements become much harder to control. The worst parts of her condition temporarily prevents her from jumping and can end an otherwise normal jump prematurely, causing her to fall back down, which makes it somewhat difficult to get *to* the abandoned commercial facility through the normal paths I take.

After running through this chapter a few times and angrily mashing the jump button near short ledges in the hopes I'll regain the ability to jump for a long enough period to climb up, I am wondering if there is a path that is intended to be used that does *not* require me to make jumps. Does such a path to the abandoned commercial facility exist from the Flooded City, or am I being too optimistic?

Comment: When I was there I accidentally fall into flooded cave in the center of city ruins, and saved there. It was HELL to get out of there because of virus 2B can't use a ladder properly.

Answer (score 2):

After much trial and error, I think I've figured out the easiest way to get to the abandoned commercial facility with minimal jumping. Unfortunately, this path still requires a single jump, but I haven't had any issues with virus infection ruining my jump (yet).

Naturally, there are spoilers related to this part of the game, but the path I took can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/IrDBrZ5n_RQ).

To summarize the path taken:

Once you emerge from the sewer that leads to the city ruins area from the Flooded City, make an immediate **left** (not straight ahead or to the right, like I was always inclined to do...), into the hole in the building, then fall one level, but not any further. Run up the ramp to the right, then do a 180 and run up the long ramp. Run past the pillars until you reach the wall of the abandoned building, then turn left. This is the jump that the machines make in the [Parade Escort](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Parade+Escort) side quest, but you're coming at it from the *opposite* direction. Wait until you are able to jump, then cross the gap. From this point forward, the way to the commercial facility is extremely simple. You will basically just keep running straight until you get to the bridge to the commercial facility.

Comment: Pretty sure I've taken a really long but jumpless path through that part, gonna be going back through it to double check (though dang do I dislike that part now after doing it 3 or 4 times for the various endings) then I can post it as an answer. I didn't even realize there were paths that you could take with jumps, but I was also always too anxious to stand around waiting for it to come back.

Comment: @Tylor When I went through this part for my first time, I fell down into the gorge. In my book, I feel like any path is better than the one I took

Comment: @Wondercricket that happened to me once as well, haha. That ladder was a nightmare.

Comment: @Tylor the first time I did this part, I basically reused the route from the first Speedstar race. You know, the one where you have to climb up that giant tree root and then jump up a building about 5 times. That was the baseline for asking this question, honestly.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the more specific question of "Is there a path that requires no jumps", the answer is **yes**. The path requires you to go a much longer way than you may expect with other paths with jumps in them, but it still shouldn't take you too long.

The path is simple enough, you go straight and a bit left out of the tunnel. There's a large building there, that you can hug the right side of to avoid falling down into the pit too far. This is more or less the same as [this video linked](https://youtu.be/IrDBrZ5n_RQ) in the previous answer, up until about the 1:25 mark. At that point, you keep going towards that direction you were heading, up the large slope, instead of turning, towards all the main buildings and the entrance to the desert. There will be some enemies on this slope that could mess you up if you get unlucky, but you'll still be low enough on contamination to be able to get away from them with a bit of care.

Once you get up the slope, all you have to do is weave through the buildings and then head off to the mall. There are more enemies close to the desert entrance and the widest part of the road that could start to become a problem, but going through the buildings near the City Ruins: Center transporter will keep you safe.

I tried to record my path as well but the recordings have failed to save, so instead of dealing with that, below is a screenshot of the map with a rough idea of the path taken, mostly for how to go through the buildings.

[image: Rough outline of the path taken]